# Complete deadlock on PostgreSQL 9.3 after removing a numeric id

Tags: postgresql-9.3, deadlock

## The problem - complete DB lock after a schema change

### Architecture

I use a PostgreSQL 9.3 with [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) to store location updates. The updates are written to two tables - `location_updates` and `location_updates_history`.

Each had:

- An auto-incrementing numeric id
- A textual `car_id`
- `geom` column

Each update was written to the `location_updates` table, and then a trigger function would write the same update to `location_updates_history`. After the update, all updates except for the latest 10 for this `car_id` would have been deleted. Therefore, the `location_update` table contained the latest 10 updates for each car in a moving-window fashion, and the `location_updates_history` table had the entire history of it.

### The change

I figured out that I only need the latest update for each car, not the latest 10, so I run the following:

```
DROP TRIGGER location_update_insertion_trigger ON location_update;
DELETE FROM location_update WHERE id NOT IN 
            (SELECT max(id) FROM location_update GROUP BY cat_id);
ALTER TABLE location_update DROP COLUMN id CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE location_update ADD PRIMARY KEY (car_id);
```

### The lock

After a few hours of work, the DB was in a complete lock - so bad that even a pg_dump on its schema was blocked.

With some help from the excellent support team on AWS RDS, and [this blog post](http://ghostwritten-insomnia.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/show-blocking-postgres-processes-and.html), I was able to draw this locking schema - in short, everybody was blocking everybody. This has been going on for days, and only stops when I manually kill the listed processes on the calling machines.

[image]

The `UPDATE` statements are of the form:

```
UPDATE TABLE location_update SET ... WHERE car_id='car_XXX';
```

The `LOCK` statements are of the form:

```
LOCK TABLE public.location_update IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

The `SELECT` statements query the `location_update` table.

**Why is my DB locked on the `location_updates` table? Was removing the numeric id the reason for that? What's the right way to fix it?**

Comment: Nice image but it would be better if you posted the actual `update` statements and the table definitions, including the triggers.

Comment: And did you run these 4 statements inside a transaction?

Comment: @ypercube 1. Updated (no pun intended) my question - all `UPDATE` statements change the `location_update` table based on its `car_id`; 2. Each query was executed separately, not within the same transaction.

Comment: What client is doing the explicit `LOCK` statements?

Comment: @CraigRinger What client identification is needed? IP address, a-la `client_addr` of the `pg_stat_admin` table?

Comment: @AdamMatan That's more a debugging tip for you. What application (s), what are they doing, etc.

Comment: Why do you lock explicitly at all? It has no effect without a transaction block around it - what else is in the same transaction, in what order?

Comment: I don't lock explicitly. Maybe it's something SQLAlchemy is doing behind the scene?