# PostgreSQL 9.3: Minimize locking when updating a large table with primary key

Tags: postgresql-9.3, update, primary-key, locking

I am building a [DB solution to handle a fast stream of online events](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108814/upsert-ing-large-batches-in-postgresql-9-3-on-aws-rds).

Each event UPSERTs a row in a `location_update` table, using its `car_id` primary key. Since there are very few new `car_id`s, the vast majority of events trigger an UPDATE.

Since the table very frequently read by SELECT statements, I would like to minimize any locking and blocking delays on the table, and especially prevent a single UPDATE from blocking a large number of SELECTs.

**How do I minimize Read/Write locking time on a table being UPDATEd using a primary key?**

Comment: What sort of (b)locking do you see currently?  How long your `UPDATE`s run?

Comment: I'm currently having a different problem of [a complete deadlock](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108799/complete-deadlock-on-postgresql-9-3-after-removing-a-numeric-id). This is more of a best-practice question in general.

Comment: 9.5 will have [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE` ("UPSERT")](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29)

Comment: You can use a writable CTE. See this fine answer at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/8702291#8702291

Comment: Another great answer, by Craig Ringer: [How do I do an UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT … ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)